# Verify if it's a string python

Tags: python, string

So, I have to make a 3x3 board. My columns are (a,b,c) and my rows (1,2,3).
I have this position to creat positions, who receives 2 strings and gives the position.

How do I verify my arguments?
I have this, and I don't know what conditions am I missing to evaluate my arguments.

I want this interaction to happen:

```
>>> p1 = create_position('a', '4')
Traceback (most recent call last): <...>
ValueError: create_position: invalid arguments
>>> p1 = create_position('a', '2')
>>> p2 = create_position('b', '3')
```

My function:

```
def create_position(c, r):
    if isinstance(c, str) and c in ('a', 'b', 'c') and isinstance(r, str):
        return (c, r)
    raise ValueError('creat position: invalid arguments')
```

Comment: So you want to verify that the second argument is a string by raising an exception if it's a string?

Comment: i tried the method is clearly working for me. I would suggest to check the indentation once

Comment: This works for me.  I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: The code would be safer if you used `else` for the raise condition. That said, why check the type in the first place, while you can just pass only strings as arguments?

Comment: Very minor terminology suggestion: if you have 'columns' then you should have 'rows' (not 'lines'). Also, 'create' is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use built-in methods for strings:

```
def creat_position(c, r):
    if c in ('a','b','c'):
        # Cast as string and check specific value.
        # Generally, not a best practice.
        if str(c).isalpha() and str(r).isnumeric():
            return (c, r)
        # Inappropriate argument type.
        raise TypeError('creat position: invalid argument type')
    else:
        # Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
        raise ValueError("creat position: invalid value for 'c'")
```

Test 1:

```
>>> creat_position('a', '4')
```

Out -

```
('a', '4')
```

Test 2:

```
>>> creat_position('a', 'b')
```

Out -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-5b182ca97075>", line 1, in <module>
    creat_position('a', 'b')

  File "<ipython-input-12-1ceb27c7e3c0>", line 6, in creat_position
    raise TypeError('creat position: invalid argument type')

TypeError: creat position: invalid argument type
```